# Excel name character restriction

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to get around the excel name characters restriction?

Say I have a sheet A with a list of names of n universities in the U.S., now I need to write a VBA code to create n new sheets and copy the names in sheet A to name those n sheets correspondingly. I am able to write codes to do this. However, there is one problem that is so annoying is that: some of the names in sheet A might have too many characters that exceed the maximal character limit of the sheet name Excel allows. Then my program will be interrupted, and I need to name the sheet myself, then rerun the program. How can I solve this?

```
UniversityName = Worksheets("A").Cells("A" & i).Value
Sheets("Sheet1 (2)").Select
Sheets("Sheet1 (2)").Name = UniversityName
```

One way that I can think of to resolve this is to define UniversityName2 = Left[UniversityName, 30]. However it would cause something like "New York Universi"and I really need it to be something that makes sense though not complete. Then a plausible way is to first let it judge whether the length of UniversityName is over 30, if true. Then define UniversityName2 to be such that it contains the maximal possible complete information. In this example it would be New York.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not abbreviate the state names so in your example NY University.

Comment: ..and/or replace "University" with "Uni" or "Univ".  There's no built-in way to do this - you'd need to define some rules and code them in a function.  If the rules don't solve the length problem then pop up an Input asking for an alternative name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should check to see if the last word is spelled correctly, and remove it if it is not. (Untested as I do not have Excel on this machine - corrections welcome)

```
UniversityName2 = Left$(UniversityName, 30)
Dim v as Variant
v = Split(UniversityName2, " ")
If Not Application.CheckSpelling(v(Ubound(v))) Then
  ReDim Preserve v(Ubound(v) - 1)
End If
Dim item as String
UniversityName2 = ""
For Each item In v
  UniversityName2 = UniversityName2 & " " & item & " "
Next
UniversityName2 = Trim$(UniversityName2)
```

You may also want to consider adding some sort of check to see if there is already a sheet with the same name, because if there is, you will get an error as 2 sheets cannot have the same name.

Comment: Very brilliant!!! Thank you very much! I modified it a little bit though. Instead of using Checkspelling, I created a u = Split(UniversityName, " ") then used a loop to compare v and u. Checkspelling would not work if my name contains something that does not make sense.